# Wrapping DOM structure with span and lowering opacity doesn't work. Why?

Tags: html, css, opacity

Here is [a codepen link](http://codepen.io/ethangodt/pen/pbVbxB) illustrating my problem.

I'd like to be able to wrap a div (with it's own complex contents) in a span and lower the opacity, but it's not working.

Solutions that work, but that I can't use:

- make the span block or inline-block (or use a div or something)
- set the wrapped div's opacity value to inherit

But why won't wrapping with a span work?

```
<!-- unwrapped -->
<div>
  <p>Here is some DOM stuff</p>
</div>

<!-- wrapped but not working -->
<span style="opacity: .5;">
  <div>
    <p>Here is some DOM stuff</p>
  </div>
</span>

<!-- wrapped and working — I don't have luxury to do this, however -->
<span style="display: block; opacity: .3">
  <div>
    <p>Here is some DOM stuff</p>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: what do you want actually your question is bit confusing

Comment: @M.Tanzil It's not confusing - OP wants to change the opacity of an element and it's not working.

Comment: @nicael in codepen its working, atleast he forgot to add `opacity` in css for corresponding `div`.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Nope, OP forgot nothing and it's not working in the codepen.

Comment: noob-in-need, You can't use divs? Why this strange restriction?

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You can't put a div in a span.

Answer (score 3):

It *does* work actually, just not in WebKit/Blink browsers like Chrome, Safari, and Opera. This is a long standing issue in WebKit-derived browsers.

## Example showing the issue:

```css
.block {
    display: block;
}
.inline {
    display: inline;
}
.inline-no-children {
    display: inline;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.block-no-children {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.inline-with-children {
    display: inline;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.block-with-children {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<span class="inline-no-children">inline no children</span>
<hr />
<span class="block-no-children">block no children</span>
<hr />
<span class="inline-with-children">
    inline with children:
    <span class="block">block (fails to become transparent in WebKit/Blink)</span>
    <span class="inline">inline</span>
</span>
<hr />
<span class="block-with-children">
    block with children:
    <span class="block">block</span>
    <span class="inline">inline</span>
</span>
```

## Side-note:

Though not the cause of the issue (as we can see above, tag name is irrelevant), it's technically invalid to wrap block elements (`div` tags) in inline elements (`span` tags). You really should be using a block display element like `div` here.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements can contain only inline-block and inline elements. Block elements don't have such restriction.

So the option is to either make all the inner elements inline-block / inline or make the span block (as you did in the second example) or use a block element instead of the span, e.g. div.